# Coded UI test is not running while setting the UIElementText in the Playback

Tags: wpf, coded-ui-tests

I have recorded the coded UI test using the VS2015 Coded UI Test builder. based on my recording the following function is created for my test method,

```
    public void RecordedMethod1()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WpfText uIItemText = this.UIMainWindowWindow.UIAddNewRowControlCustom.UIGridCellCustom.UIItemText;
        WpfEdit uIItemEdit = this.UIMainWindowWindow.UIAddNewRowControlCustom.UIGridCellCustom.UIItemEdit;
        WpfText uIItemText1 = this.UIMainWindowWindow.UIAddNewRowControlCustom.UIGridCellCustom1.UIItemText;
        #endregion

        // Double-Click label
        Mouse.DoubleClick(uIItemText, new Point(73, 3));

        //// Failed in the following line and the test is not running after that.
        // Type 'aaa' in text box
        uIItemEdit.Text = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIItemEditText;

        // Double-Click label
        Mouse.DoubleClick(uIItemText1, new Point(79, 10));

        // Type 'bbb' in text box
        uIItemEdit.Text = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIItemEditText1;

        // Type '{Enter}' in text box
        Keyboard.SendKeys(uIItemEdit, this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIItemEditSendKeys, ModifierKeys.None);
    }
```

After reaching the line to set the recorded value to the uiEditItem.Text the test case is not running further cased the failure in the test case.

I have googled for the solution and have found a one that says, you need to rewrite the test cases with the Kebord.SendKeys instead of directly setting the value to the Text property of the EditItem.

By this way I have made my code changes at the line as follows and its working.

```
// Type 'aaa' in text box
//uIItemEdit.Text = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIItemEditText;

// Replaced the above line with the SenKeys 
Keyboard.SendKeys(this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIItemEditText);
```

Is that the only solution for this problem (Manullay rewrite the test methods by using the SendKeys method instead of directly assigning a value to the uiEditItem.Text property) ? If not, please provide the feasible solution for this.